# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' WPF C#

Tags: c#

Yo, been working with **Console.Application** up until now.
And I have the following error which I do not know how to solve this is my code,

```
    private void CpuLabel_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CpuLabel.Content = GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "Name");
    }

    private static void GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
        foreach (var mj in mos.Get())
        {
            Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]);
        }
    }
```

On  a basic console application I would just have it

```
Console.Writeline(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
```

and than call for the method like this:

```
GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "Name");
```

How ever I want to bind that to my CpuLabel, how would I go ahead and do that ?

Comment: You're calling `GetComponent`, which is declared with a `void` return type... but you're trying to assign the *result* to `CpuLabel.Content`. What do you expect that to do? There *is* no result... It's not clear what you expect your `GetComponent` method to actually achieve, to be honest - you're calling `Convert.ToString` in a loop, but ignoring the return value of that...

Comment: GetComponent is `void` so it returns nothing. See [C# Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your method doesnt have return type. Change void to type what u need to return. e.g if u want to return string try this :

```
 private static string GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
        foreach (var mj in mos.Get())
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
        }

       return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: lol .. i know... it is because u need to change "SomeType" in my example to type what u need.